# Intent.getData() в UTF-8

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго времени!

Пишу приложение для открытия файлов через Intent.

Нужно достать путь к файлу способом `Intent.getData()`, а потом этим же способом перезаписать файл.

Впринцыпе все работает, если путь к файлу без пробелов и на латинице )

Проблема следующая:
**getData()** заменяет пробелы и русские символы на **%20%D0%** и тд..

Соответственно при перезаписи создается новый файл с этим же **%20%D0%**-именем.

Кому не трудно, подскажите способ получать путь в кодировке **UTF-8**, и чтобы при этом у **FileOutputStream** не было проблем с перезаписью.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+Dfile.encoding

Comment: Это что-то не то, либо я чего-то не понимаю. Причем тут батники? Приложение пишется для Android причем на Android в приложении AIDE. Все работает, вот только мне нужно, чтобы intent.getData() поддерживал пробелы и кириллицу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `getData()` нет проблем с кириллицей, это вы его неправильно интерпретируете.
Если посмотреть внимательно, то `getData()` возвращает `Uri`, соответсвенно все что не ANSI, кодируется по правилам URL encoding
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Конвертируйте Uri в file path (не всегда возможно) и все будет как надо.

**ADDON:** `Uri.getPath()` сам все декодирует

```
String linkUtf8 = "https://site.com/%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82/";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(linkUtf8);
System.out.println(uri.toString());
// >> https://site.com/%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82/
System.out.println(uri.getPath());
// >> /ссылка куда-то ведет/
```

Answer (score 1):

Как раз перед вашим ответом нашел этот способ:

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
try {
    String totalFile = new File(uri.toString());
    String fpath = URLDecoder.decode(totalF.getCanonicalPath().toString(), "UTF-8");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed on reading File: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: URLDecoder не нужен, есть вот такой метод: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#decode(java.lang.String)

Comment: Да и он, наверное, тоже не нужен, когда есть вот: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#getPath()